# htaccess force https prevents downstream proxy rule

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using an htaccess rewrite rule to redirect subdirectory values as a variable:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/members/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])(.*)$ http://example.com/index.php?username=$1 [P,L]
```

This works great and uses the P flag so the URL displayed in the browser doesn't redirect. However, when I add the code to force the domain to run via https...

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/members/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])(.*)$ http://example.com/index.php?username=$1 [P,L]
```

...this causes the URL in the browser to change. For example:

https://example.com/myvariable

redirects in the browser address bar to:

https://example.com/index.php?username=myvariable

It does successfully force the SSL, but how can I accomplish both at the same time without the URL changing?

Answer (score 0):

After a ton more testing I was able to determine that removing the domain from the rewrite rule as well as the [P] flag and it works:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/members/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])(.*)$ /index.php?username=$1 [L]
```